# How to mount a single 100TB SSD on AWS and access the device over nfs from different machines within the same VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a bad experience with [Storage Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/) (SGW) and would to consider the possibility to setup a 100TB SSD device (via EFS or similar) on AWS and allow an access to the storage device from different clients such as: Amazon Workspaces sessions, EC2 machines, AWS Batch and other station within the same VPC.

The main issue is that SGW fails quite frequently to mirror the s3 bucket properly even after 24 hours upon update of the bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create storage in AWS Console
2. mount created storage into VM
3. configure nfs deamon to present the storage volume in the VPC
4. configure Clients to use/mount NFS volume coming from server

sometimes the easiest is the best, this even works on other systems, not just AWS.

Comment: Any suggestion how to mirror efficiently data from s3 to this storage?

Comment: the other way would be better. Using S3 as backup.